# magento2: admin grid showing joined table

Tags: magento2, backend

For now, I am able to use a admin grid to show a custom table(contactus_map_location):
[image]

but I want to have a store view column in my grid and according to the cms page module, I should have a separate table(contactus_map_location_store) to join the original table and show it.

I tried to use the method in cms_page module but it does not work. Here comes my code:
app\code\Company\Module\etc\di.xml:

Company\Module\Model\Resource\Grid\Collection
            ContactusGridFilterPool

```
<!-- Create our type ContactusGridFilterPool -->
<virtualType name="ContactusGridFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
            <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>

<!-- Type for jobs_department_listing_data_source -->
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="contactus_grid_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<!-- Simulate our class Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Grid\Collection -->
<virtualType name="Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">contactus_map_location</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Grid</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

app\code\Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Grid.php:

```
    <?php
namespace Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel;

use \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

/**
 * Grid post mysql resource
 */
class Grid extends AbstractDb
{
    const GRID_ID = 'entity_id'; // We define the id fieldname

    /**
     * Prefix of model events names
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'contactus'; // parent value is 'core_abstract'

    /**
     * Name of the event object
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventObject = 'grid'; // parent value is 'object'

    /**
     * Name of object id field
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_idFieldName = self::GRID_ID;
    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected $_store = null;

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime
     */
    protected $dateTime;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime $dateTime,
        $connectionName = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $connectionName);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->dateTime = $dateTime;
    }
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('contactus_map_location', 'entity_id');
    }

    protected function _afterLoad(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object)
    {
        if ($object->getId()) {
            $stores = $this->lookupStoreIds($object->getId());

            $object->setData('store_id', $stores);
        }

        return parent::_afterLoad($object);
    }

    public function lookupStoreIds($location_id)
    {
        $connection = $this->getConnection();

        $select = $connection->select()->from(
            $this->getTable('contactus_map_location_store'),
            'store_id'
        )->where(
            'location_id = ?',
            (int)$location_id
        );

        return $connection->fetchCol($select);
    }
}
```

app\code\Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractCollection.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel;

/**
 * Abstract collection of CMS pages and blocks
 */
abstract class AbstractCollection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface|null $connection
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb|null $resource
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * Perform operations after collection load
     *
     * @param string $tableName
     * @param string $columnName
     * @return void
     */
    protected function performAfterLoad($tableName, $columnName)
    {
        $items = $this->getColumnValues($columnName);
        if (count($items)) {
            $connection = $this->getConnection();
            $select = $connection->select()->from(['cms_entity_store' => $this->getTable($tableName)])
                ->where('cms_entity_store.' . $columnName . ' IN (?)', $items);
            $result = $connection->fetchPairs($select);
            if ($result) {
                foreach ($this as $item) {
                    $entityId = $item->getData($columnName);
                    if (!isset($result[$entityId])) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if ($result[$entityId] == 0) {
                        $stores = $this->storeManager->getStores(false, true);
                        $storeId = current($stores)->getId();
                        $storeCode = key($stores);
                    } else {
                        $storeId = $result[$item->getData($columnName)];
                        $storeCode = $this->storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getCode();
                    }
                    $item->setData('_first_store_id', $storeId);
                    $item->setData('store_code', $storeCode);
                    $item->setData('store_id', [$result[$entityId]]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add field filter to collection
     *
     * @param array|string $field
     * @param string|int|array|null $condition
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addFieldToFilter($field, $condition = null)
    {
        if ($field === 'store_id') {
            return $this->addStoreFilter($condition, false);
        }

        return parent::addFieldToFilter($field, $condition);
    }

    /**
     * Add filter by store
     *
     * @param int|array|\Magento\Store\Model\Store $store
     * @param bool $withAdmin
     * @return $this
     */
    abstract public function addStoreFilter($store, $withAdmin = true);

    /**
     * Perform adding filter by store
     *
     * @param int|array|\Magento\Store\Model\Store $store
     * @param bool $withAdmin
     * @return void
     */
    protected function performAddStoreFilter($store, $withAdmin = true)
    {
        if ($store instanceof \Magento\Store\Model\Store) {
            $store = [$store->getId()];
        }

        if (!is_array($store)) {
            $store = [$store];
        }

        if ($withAdmin) {
            $store[] = \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID;
        }

        $this->addFilter('store', ['in' => $store], 'public');
    }

    /**
     * Join store relation table if there is store filter
     *
     * @param string $tableName
     * @param string $columnName
     * @return void
     */
    protected function joinStoreRelationTable($tableName, $columnName)
    {
        if ($this->getFilter('store')) {
            $this->getSelect()->join(
                ['store_table' => $this->getTable($tableName)],
                'main_table.' . $columnName . ' = store_table.' . $columnName,
                []
            )->group(
                'main_table.' . $columnName
            );
        }
        parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
    }

    /**
     * Get SQL for get record count
     *
     * Extra GROUP BY strip added.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\DB\Select
     */
    public function getSelectCountSql()
    {
        $countSelect = parent::getSelectCountSql();
        $countSelect->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::GROUP);

        return $countSelect;
    }
}
```

app\code\Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection.php:

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Grid;

use \Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{

    protected $_idFieldName = 'entity_id';

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Company\Module\Model\Grid', 'Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Grid');
    }
    public function addStoreFilter($store, $withAdmin = true)
    {
        if (!$this->getFlag('store_filter_added')) {
            $this->performAddStoreFilter($store, $withAdmin);
        }
        return $this;
    }

}
```

app\code\Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\CollectionFactory.php:

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Grid;

class CollectionFactory
{
    /**
     * Object Manager instance
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager = null;

    /**
     * Instance name to create
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_instanceName = null;

    /**
     * Factory constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     * @param string $instanceName
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager, $instanceName = '\\Company\\Module\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Grid\\Collection')
    {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_instanceName = $instanceName;
    }

    /**
     * Create class instance with specified parameters
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return \Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Department\Collection
     */
    public function create(array $data = array())
    {
        return $this->_objectManager->create($this->_instanceName, $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created admin grid which has join of two custom tables. you cannot do this by using virtual type is di.xml, so you need to follow these steps and update your

etc/di.xml,

Model/ResourceModel/Modulename/Collection.php add join in this file,

Model/ResourceModel/Modulename/Grid/Collection.php,

IN your etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="namespace_modulename_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Modulename\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Modulename\Grid\Collection">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">tablename</argument>
        <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">namespace_modulename_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">namespace_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Modulename</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

IN your Model/ResourceModel/Modulename/Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Modulename;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * Define model & resource model
     */
    const YOUR_TABLE = 'tablename';

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        $this->_init(
            'Namespace\Modulename\Model\Modulename',
            'Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Modulename'
        );
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection,
            $resource
        );
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();

        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('tablename')],
                'main_table.columnname = secondTable.columnname',
                ['columnname1','columnname2','columnname3']
            );
    }
}
?>
```

In your Model/ResourceModel/Modulename/Grid/Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Modulename\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Search\AggregationInterface;
use Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Modulename\Collection as ModulenameCollection;

/**
 * Class Collection
 * Collection for displaying grid
 */
class Collection extends ModulenameCollection implements SearchResultInterface
{
    /**
     * Resource initialization
     * @return $this
     */
   public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document',
        $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory,
            $logger,
            $fetchStrategy,
            $eventManager,
            $storeManager,
            $connection,
            $resource
        );
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
    }

    /**
     * @return AggregationInterface
     */
    public function getAggregations()
    {
        return $this->aggregations;
    }

    /**
     * @param AggregationInterface $aggregations
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAggregations($aggregations)
    {
        $this->aggregations = $aggregations;
    }


    /**
     * Get search criteria.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface|null
     */
    public function getSearchCriteria()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Set search criteria.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria
     *
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setSearchCriteria(
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria = null
    ) {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get total count.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getTotalCount()
    {
        return $this->getSize();
    }

    /**
     * Set total count.
     *
     * @param int $totalCount
     *
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set items list.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface[] $items
     *
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setItems(array $items = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: works, but fail at filtering by the joined field

Comment: it's not working, in my case my data provider name is "manage_qamanage_index_data_source" then in eventPrefix value "manage_qamanage_grid_collection", other than that everything is same , but still the custom column name is blank. Then is there have any possibility to see the query?

Comment: How can we join only for grid? By doing this, it also changing default model collection where we dont need to join collection.

Comment: I have studied your solution and it is not work at all. After recompiling the code there is an issue: The class mentioned in the xml Type within the di.xml file does not exist!