# how to create grid using ui component with multi table(JOIN) in magento2?

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent, json

I have created a grid with UI component with one table now I want to join another table so how can I create??

i try but not working 
in
Vendorname\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\collection.php

```
protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();

        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('quote_customer')],
                'main_table.mcs_quote_id = secondTable.quote_request_id',
                array('*')
            );
    }
```

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what error are display?

Comment: not get any error but did not get second table filed

Comment: quote_customer is your custom table? Have you check value getting or not?

Comment: yes i am checking but not get value i have add screen shot please check it

Comment: is quote_customer your custom table?

Comment: main table - quote,  sub table - quote_customer

Comment: By default quote_customer table is not available in Magento CE

Comment: both table are custom

Comment: protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();

        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('quote_customer')],
                'main_table.mcs_quote_id = secondTable.quote_request_id',
                $cols = '*'
            );
        return $this;
    }

Comment: check using above code and let me know

Comment: hello rakesh still not working

Comment: you can display your both table with all field so we have clear out your issue.

Comment: yes display all field

Comment: Hello All, can't we do this using dataprovider class when define datasource in ui component xml?

Comment: How  did you resolve the problem ?

Answer (score 12):

You can display values from join two tables by using below model resource collection class function

Add below function to your model resource collection function

```
protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();

        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('tablename')],
                'main_table.columnname = secondTable.columnname',
                ['columnname1','columnname2','columnname3']
            );
    }
```

You can get more information from here [magento2: admin grid showing joined table](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117451/magento2-admin-grid-showing-joined-table)

Comment: hello ,i try but it is not working

Comment: hello,It's working on initial load page but when we try to filter out on that filed it's give me error Column not found..

Comment: For this we have to use addFilterToMap() in initselect() for filtering otherwise Good solution +1

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thanks!

Comment: it fetches both table column, is there anyway it fetch only one table.

Answer (score 9):

Add _initSelect method to Collection.php file in Vendorname\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\collection.php With below code

**IMPORTANT**: Please add **addFilterToMap** to initSelect Moethod Otherwise **Sorting** and **Filtering** not work with Join.

```
 protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();

    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('tablename')],
            'main_table.columnname = secondTable.columnname',
            ['columnname1_alias'=>'columnname1','columnname2_clias' => 'columnname2']
        );
 $this->addFilterToMap('columnname1_alias', 'secondTable.columnname1');
 $this->addFilterToMap('columnname2_clias', 'secondTable.columnname2');
    return $this;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: it fetches both table column, is there anyway it fetch only one table.

Answer (score 4):

Using the comments above, I've added the join to the Grid in a pretty simple and straightforward way. To have the joined tables, you cannot use Virtual type tables. So, that's how you make it happens

In your etc/di.xml add:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="vendor_module_yourtablemodel_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\YourTableModel\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then, create the Collection, Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\YourTableModel\Grid\Collection.php

and add the content below:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\YourTableModel\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface as FetchStrategy;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface as EntityFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;

class Collection extends SearchResult
{
    protected $_idFieldName = 'id';

    public function __construct(
        EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        Logger $logger,
        FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy,
        EventManager $eventManager,
        $mainTable = 'your_table',
        $resourceModel = 'Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\YourTableModel',
        $identifierName = null,
        $connectionName = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $mainTable, $resourceModel, $identifierName, $connectionName);
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|void
     */
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();

        // Join the 2nd Table
        $this->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(
                ['some_other_table_alias' => $this->getConnection()->getTableName('some_other_table')],
                'main_table.some_other_table_id = some_other_table_alias.id',
                ['some_other_table_column1', 'some_other_table_column2']
            );
    }
}
```

Flush the cache and it should work.

Comment: thanks it working

Comment: while filtering main_table column get error

Comment: @mohan, in the method _initSelect(), print out $this->getSelect(); and see what the SQL looks like. The main table my have a different alias in your query.

Comment: yes your correct. i was fixed this issue.

Comment: it fetches both table column, is there anyway it fetch only one table.

Comment: 1+ work for me thank you

Comment: @AliRaza, you can reset the columns and re-add them. $_updates->getSelect()
    ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)->columns('col1')

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected function _renderFiltersBefore() {
        $joinTable = $this->getTable('quote_customer');

        $this->getSelect()->JoinLeft($joinTable.' as secondtable','main_table.id = secondtable.id', array('columnname'));
        parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
   }
```